# How to solve SDEs using Ito's Lemma

Tags: stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm self-learning SDEs and trying to understand how to solve SDEs using Ito's Lemma, so when given a general SDE, how can one choose the function to use? This is an example I found

$$ dX = \frac{1}{X} dt + \alpha X dB_t, X_0=x>0$$

Firstly, since there is a $dt$ and $dB_t$ terms, would we choose the bivariate Ito formula such that
$$ df(t,X) = f(0,X_0) +\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial X_t} dX_t + \frac{\partial f^2(t,x)}{\partial X_t^2}d\langle X\rangle $$
I guess, since we know behaviour of BM, we should make the function in terms of $B_t$, because then we can simplify $d\langle B_t\rangle=dt$

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/998811/36150)