# How to solve this stochastic differential equation, $dx_t=\mu dt+(\sigma-\bar{\sigma}x_t)dW_t$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I have this stochastic differential equation which I would like to solve:

$$
dx_t=\mu dt+(\sigma-\bar{\sigma}x_t)dW_t
$$

It is similar to the mean-reverting process, but variance-reverting kind. No such simple solving method exists as far as I tried.

Comment: It's a particular case of a linear SDE and there a standard techniques to solve such SDEs... you will find several related questions if you search for "linear SDE", e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/592995/36150).